# ChildTheme CSS fix for date box

Tags: css, wordpress

Since last time the help was awesome I will once again try my luck..

So I am building a custom made Wordpress theme but I am stuck on a specific CSS related "feature".

I am trying to add a date box outside the main content "Table" next to each post, exactly like the Bouquet theme here: http://wp-themes.com/bouquet/

I've noticed that it is mainly the entry-header that does all the work so I pretty much grabbed the CSS code from bouquet, played a bit around, altered the function to include the entry-header div but it still looks like -.-"..

Because I am currently working on the theme offline on my local server I can show you a print screen of it: hxp://s24.postimg.org/cows6mvdh/fix_this.png or full page here: http://oi39.tinypic.com/11j7ptz.jpg

From my understanding it seems like it ignores the page's max-width and instead is using full page width and that's why the date is shown like that :/

Here is my CSS (I am still learning so please be kind tyvm):

```
    /* =Reset
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* Corrects text resizing oddly in IE6/7 when body font-size is set using em units http://clagnut.com/blog/348/#c790 */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Keeps page centred in all browsers regardless of content height */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/ */
}
body {
    background: #fff;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table { /* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}
a:hover,
a:active { /* Improves readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers people.opera.com/patrickl/experiments/keyboard/test */
    outline: 0;
}
a img {
    border: 0;
}


/* =Global
----------------------------------------------- */

body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #6b6252; 
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
    background: #FAFAFA;
}

/* Headings */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0.6em 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-size: 3.6rem;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
hr {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

/* Text elements */
p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
ul, ol {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em;
}
ul {
    list-style: disc;
}
ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}
ul ul, ol ol, ul ol, ol ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}
dd {
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}
b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
dfn, cite, em, i {
    font-style: italic;
}
blockquote {
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0 1.5em;
}
address {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
pre {
    background: #dfd6c7;
    font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    padding: 1.6em;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
code, kbd, tt, var {
    font: 15px Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
}
abbr, acronym {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    cursor: help;
}
mark, ins {
    background: #fff9c0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
sup,
sub {
    font-size: 75%;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
    bottom: 1ex;
}
sub {
    top: .5ex;
}
small {
    font-size: 75%;
}
big {
    font-size: 125%;
}
figure {
    margin: 0;
}
table {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
th {
    font-weight: bold;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* Corrects font size not being inherited in all browsers */
    margin: 0; /* Addresses margins set differently in IE6/7, F3/4, S5, Chrome */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* Improves appearance and consistency in all browsers */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* Improves appearance and consistency in all browsers */
}
button,
input {
    line-height: normal; /* Addresses FF3/4 setting line-height using !important in the UA stylesheet */
    *overflow: visible;  /* Corrects inner spacing displayed oddly in IE6/7 */
}
button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #ccc #ccc #bbb #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    cursor: pointer; /* Improves usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type 'input' and others */
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* Corrects inability to style clickable 'input' types in iOS */
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 1.12em 1.5em 1em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
button:hover,
html input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border-color: #ccc #bbb #aaa #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}
button:focus,
html input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
button:active,
html input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="reset"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    border-color: #aaa #bbb #bbb #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Addresses box sizing set to content-box in IE8/9 */
    padding: 0; /* Addresses excess padding in IE8/9 */
}
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* Addresses appearance set to searchfield in S5, Chrome */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* Addresses box sizing set to border-box in S5, Chrome (include -moz to future-proof) */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration { /* Corrects inner padding displayed oddly in S5, Chrome on OSX */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner { /* Corrects inner padding and border displayed oddly in FF3/4 www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/14/the-devils-in-the-details-fixing-dojos-toolbar-buttons/ */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
textarea {
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3 );
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
textarea:focus {
    background: #fff;
}
textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* Removes default vertical scrollbar in IE6/7/8/9 */
    padding-left: 3px;
    vertical-align: top; /* Improves readability and alignment in all browsers */
    width: 98%;
}

/* Links */
/*a,
a:visited {
    color: #748a81;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #33605a;
}*/

a {
    color:#1c9bdc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:focus,
a:active,
a:hover {
    color: #1873a1;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Alignment */
.alignleft {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.alignright {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
}

/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.assistive-text {
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    position: absolute !important;
}

.site-title,
.entry-title,
.page-title,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary,
.widget-title,
.comments-title,
.comment .reply,
.comment-meta,
.comment-author,
#reply-title {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}


/* =Structure
----------------------------------------------- */

#main,
.main-navigation,
.site-title,
.site-description {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1180px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #9F9F9F;
}
#main {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -27% 0 0;
    padding: 2em;
    width: 88%;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 23% 0 0;
}
#secondary,
#tertiary {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    margin: 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 22%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
#tertiary {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.site-footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}


/* =Site Header
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-header hgroup {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
    text-align: center
}
.site-title {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    font-style: italic;
}
.site-description {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;  
}
.site-title a,
.site-description {
    color: #2E2E2E;
}


/* =Menu
----------------------------------------------- */

.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em;
}
.main-navigation:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation a {
    color: #7c948a;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1 );
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
        top: 1.2em;
        left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    width: 200px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a,
.main-navigation li.current_page_item a,
.main-navigation li.current-menu-item a,
.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
    color: #33605a;
}
.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
    color: #7c948a;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-small-navigation .menu {
    display: none;
}


/* =Content
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-main {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-width: 3px 1px;
}
.sticky {
}
.hentry {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.entry-title,
.page-title {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0 0 0.2em;
}
.entry-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.entry-header {
    padding: 0.6em 0;
}
.entry-date {
    background: #f8e3ea;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding: .2em 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1em;
    line-height: 3.1em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 55px;
    width: 50px;
}
.entry-date a {
    color: #63724b;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Sorts Mill Goudy', 'Times New Roman', serif;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
.entry-date a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.entry-date b {
    display: block;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0;
}


body.search .page-title,
body.archive .page-title {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.entry-meta {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.byline {
    display: none;
}
.single .byline,
.group-blog .byline {
    display: inline;
}
.entry-content,
.entry-summary {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0;
}
.entry-content table,
.comment-content table {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-left-width: 0;
    margin: 0 -0.083em 2.083em 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.entry-content tr th,
.entry-content thead th,
.comment-content tr th,
.comment-content thead th {
    border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.5em  1.25em;
}
.entry-content tr td,
.comment-content tr td {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    padding: 0.5em  1.25em;
}
.entry-content tr.odd td,
.comment-content tr.odd td {
    background: #dfd6c7;
}
.page-links {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}


/* =Aside Post Format
----------------------------------------------- */

.format-aside .entry-content {
    border-left: 4px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1 );
    padding-left: 1em;
}


/* =Media
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-header img,
.entry-content img,
.comment-content img,
.widget img {
    max-width: 100%; /* Fluid images for posts, comments, and widgets */
}
.site-header img,
.entry-content img,
.widget-img,
img[class*="align"],
img[class*="wp-image-"],
.wp-caption img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images with WordPress-added height and width attributes are scaled correctly */
}
.site-header img,
.entry-content img,
.widget img,
img.size-full {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto; /* Prevent stretching of full-size images with height and width attributes in IE8 */
}
.entry-content img.wp-smiley,
.comment-content img.wp-smiley {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wp-caption {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.wp-caption.aligncenter,
.wp-caption.alignleft,
.wp-caption.alignright,
.wp-caption.alignnone {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.wp-caption img {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.2% auto 0;
    max-width: 98%;
}
.wp-caption-text {
    text-align: center;
}
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    margin: 0.8075em 0;
}
#content .gallery {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.wp-caption-text,
.gallery-caption {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-style: italic;
}
#content .gallery a img {
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
}
#content .gallery dd {
    margin: 0;
}

/* Make sure embeds and iframes fit their containers */
embed,
iframe,
object {
    max-width: 100%;
}


/* =Navigation
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-content .site-navigation {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.site-content .nav-previous {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.site-content .nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}

/* =Comments
----------------------------------------------- */

#comments {
    clear: both;
}
.bypostauthor {
}
.comments-title,
#reply-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.commentlist li {
    list-style: none;
}
.commentlist,
.children {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.children {
    margin: 0 0 0 6%;
}
.commentlist li.comment,
.commentlist li.pingback {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
    padding-left: 2.5em;
}
.commentlist .children li,
.commentlist li:last-of-type {
    border: none;
}
article.comment,
li.pingback {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2.5em 0 0.7em;
    position: relative;
}
.children article.comment,
.children li.pingback {
    padding-top: 1.0em;
}
.comment .avatar {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
}
.comment-author {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.comment-meta {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.comment-content{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 1em 0 0 4.5em;
}
.comment .reply {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: right;
}
li.pingback {
    font-weight: bold;
}
li.pingback a {
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* Comment Form */
.comment-notes,
#commentform .form-allowed-tags,
p.nocomments,
p.logged-in-as,
#commentform label {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.required {
    color: #880000;
}
#commentform label {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
#commentform input[type="text"] {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
#commentform #comment {
    margin-top: 0.6em;
}
#commentform .form-allowed-tags,
#commentform .form-allowed-tags code {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
p.nocomments {
    margin: 2.5em;
}


/* =Widgets
----------------------------------------------- */

.widget {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}
.widget-title {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Search widget */
#searchsubmit {
    display: none;
}


/* =Site Footer
----------------------------------------------- */

.site-info {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding: 1.5em 0;
    text-align: center;
}


/* =Responsive Structures
----------------------------------------------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .entry-date {
        border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
        border-right-width: 5px;
        border-left-width: 0;
        height: 45px;
        left: -1.3em;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .entry-date a {
        margin-top: -9.5px;
    }
    #main {
        overflow: visible;
    }
    #content,
    #primary,
    #secondary,
    #tertiary {
        background: none;
        float: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #primary,
    #secondary,
    #tertiary {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .site-header hgroup,
    #main {
        padding: 0.8em;
    }
}


/* =IE Styles
----------------------------------------------- */

#ie8 .site-header img,
#ie8 .entry-content img,
#ie8 img.size-full,
#ie8 .entry-thumbnail img,
#ie8 .widget img,
#ie8 .wp-caption img {
    width: auto; /* Prevent stretching of full-size images with height and width attributes in IE8 */
}
```

Structure:

```
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<div id="main" class="site-main">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <div class="entry-date">date goes here</div>
```

Please let me know if you need something else or if I am missing some kind of information.

Comment: please upload print screen url once again. current url shows " Page is not found"

Comment: I added a full page screenshot on a different image host. Ty

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/7V2Uh/

Here I have created one "date" DOM inside Post article DOM. Set position relative to post DOM and set absolute to the date DOM and adjust the position according to your needs.

Snippet :

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="date"></div>
     This is just another article DIV.. we have date div inside it.. 
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.post{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:50px;
}

.date {
    position : absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:-50px;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#eee;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply mate, I have also added the structure I am currently using on the theme. Looks similar to what you are suggesting to me. But as I said I am a total newbie so I will give that a try :D

Comment: This didn't work after all mate. It creates the box within the content area while I want it just outside of it :(

Comment: I will post the edited answer today :-) Thanks for posting the markup